# php change variable value of included file

Tags: php

I am learning php, how do I change variable value of included file?

for eg:

**a.php**

```
$name = 'john'
```

**b.php**

```
require_once 'a.php'
$name = 'james' // here i am changing value of $name
```

**c.php**

```
echo $name //here I want to show as 'james' not 'john' , how?
```

Comment: Did you try what you share here? Just include `b.php` in `c.php`.

Comment: if you include b.php in c.php this can be achived

Comment: Please try this first since if you include `b.php` after `a.php` in `c.php` this should work.

Comment: is there any other way without including b.php in c.php? say using global variable?

Comment: @John you can use $_SESSION variables

Comment: @NareshKumar Actually there are many files using $name variable, so in my case I cannot use $_SESSION , I am wondering is that really not possible to edit variable value and fix that modified value permanently.

Comment: @John use array, and if so please share your whole situation

Comment: @NareshKumar In a.php, I have array varriable as $cfg['x']['y'] = 'john' , now I got a situation to change the value of it permanently. The above array is using in many files. So in all other files, array value should get updated value, how pls?

Comment: @John start session_start() and then assign it `$_SESSION['name'] = $cfg['x']['y']; this will save the value john in $_SESSION['name'], You can use that session variable in any page.

Comment: @NareshKumar so I need to call this $_SESSION['name']  in already existing files, in order to get updated value of $name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112911/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-and-john).

Comment: a.php
session_start()
$_SESSION['name'] = //value from the array;




b.php
session_start()

echo $_SESSION['name'];
$_SESSION['name'] = //any other value;
echo $_SESSION['name'];




output will be in b.php

value from the array
any other value

Comment: $cfg['x']['y'] is already calling in many php files, so in each file I need to call session, right?